# Entity FrameWork (ORM) e DropDownList Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho **dois** models mapeamos que vai funcionar assim :
O model **Afaze**r vai ter um **ComboBox(DropDownList)** que vai disponibilizar as categorias para o usuario selecionar, porém essas categorias são cadastradas pelo mesmo, então no fonte tenho algo assim :

```
 public class Afazer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a titulo!")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo da titulo são 1 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 30 caracteres.")]
    [Display(Name = "Titulo: ")]
    public string AFZ_TITULO { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a descrição!")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo da descrição são 5 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 256 caracteres.")]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição: ")]
    public string AFZ_DESCRICAO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nivel de Prioridade")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione um Nivel valido!")]
    public Prioridades AFZ_NIVEL { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categoria: ")]
    public virtual ICollection<Categorias> Categoria { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status: ")]
    public bool AFZ_DONE { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


}


 public class Categorias
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a categoria!")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho mínimo da categoria são 1 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "O tamanho máximo são 15 caracteres.")]
    [Display(Name = "Titulo: ")]
    public string CAT_DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


}
```

Já na minha View tentei algo assim:(**Mas não funciona**)

```html
@model Teste.Models.Afazer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Afazer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CAT_DESCRICAO", new SelectList(Model.Categoria.AsEnumerable()))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Categoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

espero que eu possa lhe ajudar.

Observe a imagem abaixo, nela você pode notar que o segundo parâmetro é do tipo `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, porém você está passando um `IEnumerable<Categorias>`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, você deve alterar lá no seu model **Afazer** o campo

```
public virtual ICollection<Categorias> Categoria { get; set; }
```

para

```
public virtual ICollection<SelectListItem> Categoria { get; set; }
```

em seguida, você deverá adicionar um novo campo em seu model **Afazer** para guardar o valor selecionado. Presumindo que você gostaria de guardar o **Id** de sua **Categoria**, adicione o seguinte campo **(no model Afazer)**:

```
public string IdCategoria { get; set; }
```

em seguida, você deverá modificar sua view para ficar desta forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdCategoria", Model.Categoria)
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o campo do seu form **Afazer** que será preenchido ao selecionar alguma categoria.

Por fim, em sua **Action**, adicione como retorno, uma nova instancia de seu model, já preenchendo seu **IEnumerable**, desta forma:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index() {
     return View("Index", new Afazer {
           Categoria = new[] {
               new SelectListItem { Text = "Categoria 1", Value = "1" },
               new SelectListItem { Text = "Categoria 2", Value = "2" },
           }
     });
}
```

Pronto, agora seu dropdown estará funcionando. Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

**Algumas dicas:**

Tenho algumas dicas para o seu código, porém isso é sómente por convenção, não precisa ser seguido.

1. Nomes de classes sempre no singular, no seu caso, a classe deveria se chamar **Categoria**;
2. Nomes de propriedades dos tipos **IEnumerable**, **ICollection** e etc, sempre no plural, no seu caso, a propriedade Categoria no model Afazer, deveria se chamar, **Categorias**;
3. Nomes de models devem conter a palavra **Model** no final, no seu caso ficaria **AfazerModel**, ou melhor ainda, para dizer que ele é um model vinculado a uma **View**, deixe o nome como **AfazerViewModel**;

**Lembrando que isto é só por convenção, para um código melhor escrito, não precisa ser seguido**

Bom, é isso. Espero ter ajudado.
Valeu!

Comment: Otima explicação, você é demais!

Comment: Valeu! Que bom que deu certo!